# How to import URL in pandas that is neither csv or Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to import this URL from the worldbank
https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD

I want to use the table of all countries and economies.

I can skip the graph by skipping the header, but `pd.read_excel` or `pd.read_csv` obviously aren't working.

What am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an link on the site to download the data as `xlsx`. You can read this with `pd.read_excel()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?downloadformat=excel', sheet_name='Data', skiprows=3)
```

result:

|  | Country Name | Country Code | Indicator Name | Indicator Code | 1960 | 1961 | 1962 | 1963 | 1964 | 1965 | 1966 | 1967 | 1968 | 1969 | 1970 | 1971 | 1972 | 1973 | 1974 | 1975 | 1976 | 1977 | 1978 | 1979 | 1980 | 1981 | 1982 | 1983 | 1984 | 1985 | 1986 | 1987 | 1988 | 1989 | 1990 | 1991 | 1992 | 1993 | 1994 | 1995 | 1996 | 1997 | 1998 | 1999 | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Aruba | ABW | GDP (current US$) | NY.GDP.MKTP.CD | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 405463417 | 487602458 | 596423607 | 695304363 | 764887117 | 872138715 | 958463184 | 1082979721 | 1245688268 | 1320474860 | 1379960894 | 1531944134 | 1665100559 | 1722798883 | 1873452514 | 1920111732 | 1941340782 | 2021229050 | 2228491620 | 2330726257 | 2424581006 | 2615083799 | 2745251397 | 2498882682 | 2390502793 | 2549720670 | 2534636872 | 2727849721 | 2790849162 | 2962905028 | 2983636872 | 3092430168 | 3202188607 | nan | nan |
| 1 | Africa Eastern and Southern | AFE | GDP (current US$) | NY.GDP.MKTP.CD | 19342484576 | 19753490586 | 21526615650 | 25772356399 | 23563232195 | 26851350246 | 29196502382 | 30219070807 | 32927067005 | 37801761961 | 40377109505 | 44544318707 | 48374959174 | 63079306619 | 78369918525 | 83562484550 | 83337002757 | 95133441245 | 106507911957 | 124687609417 | 156750816224 | 160622014029 | 154904633222 | 160000530887 | 146244041212 | 130638242469 | 147248826582 | 180012868628 | 189290783787 | 194839284973 | 212659048041 | 221099527492 | 220553773354 | 220949576766 | 225099507739 | 253136239805 | 252550100523 | 265549158044 | 250377799052 | 247067404758 | 268315059659 | 242105498360 | 247656772652 | 326744217915 | 405860474813 | 471742666480 | 533533468219 | 613164396848 | 668037143166 | 670986478461 | 805794703846 | 898604749626 | 915590443629 | 930086422790 | 958824753165 | 895440123119 | 856991850399 | 964790654431 | 986610722363 | 980371628600 | 900828558644 |
| 2 | Afghanistan | AFG | GDP (current US$) | NY.GDP.MKTP.CD | 537777811 | 548888896 | 546666678 | 751111191 | 800000044 | 1006666638 | 1399999967 | 1673333418 | 1373333367 | 1408888922 | 1748886596 | 1831108971 | 1595555476 | 1733333264 | 2155555498 | 2366666616 | 2555555567 | 2953333418 | 3300000109 | 3697940410 | 3641723322 | 3478787909 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4055179566 | 4515558808 | 5226778809 | 6209137625 | 6971285595 | 9747879532 | 10109225814 | 12439087077 | 15856574731 | 17804292964 | 20001598506 | 20561069558 | 20484885120 | 19907111419 | 18017749074 | 18869945678 | 18353881130 | 19291104008 | 19807067268 |
| 3 | Africa Western and Central | AFW | GDP (current US$) | NY.GDP.MKTP.CD | 10407321640 | 11131302981 | 11946843969 | 12680220415 | 13842621612 | 14866816737 | 15837474343 | 14430648807 | 14884699923 | 16887028428 | 23511477700 | 20838908163 | 25272340678 | 31282962686 | 44227412162 | 51459772973 | 62147555474 | 65334104528 | 71220525033 | 88654314398 | 112064063501 | 211065184010 | 187218448133 | 138155586596 | 114296077828 | 116541346401 | 107528972026 | 110354025261 | 108975317104 | 101798537787 | 121837737280 | 117491402473 | 118316836021 | 97186773684 | 85693055814 | 107403017954 | 119043576286 | 119983265523 | 122621303105 | 130198655014 | 134150161633 | 141862545778 | 170531894804 | 197384166043 | 245856459112 | 302110792974 | 384336309536 | 451866076568 | 553031246170 | 492545833171 | 580217267150 | 658428249867 | 716935231751 | 807818949699 | 846943079513 | 757492080700 | 687484728476 | 680989095101 | 738131279382 | 792078923888 | 786584975144 |
| 4 | Angola | AGO | GDP (current US$) | NY.GDP.MKTP.CD | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 5934073604 | 5553824464 | 5553824464 | 5787823809 | 6135166254 | 7558613008 | 7076793823 | 8089279285 | 8775116269 | 10207922517 | 11236275843 | nan | nan | nan | 3390500000 | 5561222222 | 7526963964 | 7649716157 | 6506619145 | 6152936539 | 9129634978 | 8936063723 | 15285594828 | 17812705294 | 23552052408 | 36970918699 | 52381006892 | 65266452081 | 88538611205 | 70307163678 | 83799496611 | 111789686464 | 128052853643 | 136709862831 | 145712200313 | 116193649124 | 101123851090 | 122123822334 | 101353230785 | 89417190341 | 62306913444 |